# Cordova iOS Statusbar StatusBarOverlaysWebView padding top

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, fullscreen

My goal is to make my app on full screen and for this purpose I use two functions:

```
StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
StatusBar.hide();
```

This is work for Android OS but on iPhone I have a body margin equals to status bar height. I don't understand why, it's looks like:

[image]

(Orange is margin equals to statusbar height and violet is the body content)

I know It's possible to make full screen because I have an other Ionic app with Cordova and when I hide status bar my app start at top of phone.

In my css I have margin and padding at 0.
I know the overlay is well taken into account because my body with 100vh outrun height of screen just my body dosn't start à top of screen.

Comment: have you use this preference for ios <platform name="ios">
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
 </platform>

Comment: Yes I tried it but doesn't work :/

Comment: safe area inset CSS could produce this if they are used. They are (incorrectly) ignored in Android Chrome (and as far as I know, it still is on the current version) but iOS correctly uses it to pad the container, based on status bar, camera notches, or other physical things that may be affecting screen real-estate. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env for more information on safe area insets.

Comment: It's really hard to give a definite answer, there isn't enough information available, another thing that you might be missing is `<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover" />` which tells iOS to utilize the entire screen.

Comment: @NormanBreau so thank you !! it's work, I just optimised with <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, user-scalable=no"
    />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solved it use
`<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`